# How to increment string within a certain range

Tags: python

I have a string like '"F01" le code le "F16"' I want to parse this string to get a new string contains "F01", "F02, "F03" ... until "F16".

I tired to parse the string by quotes and hope to loop through the first code till the last code. And then tried to increment the code via chr() and ord(). But can't seem to figure it out.

```py
import re
s = '"F01" le code le "F16"'

s_q = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', s)

first_code = s_q[0]
last_code = s_q[1]
ch_for_increment = s_q[0][-1:]
ch_for_the_rest = s_q[0][:-1]
print(ch_for_the_rest + chr(ord(ch) + 1))
```

Comment: What is the string you are looking for @GuZhao ? `F01 F02 F03 F04 F05 F06 F07 F08 F09 F10 F11 F12 F13 F14 F15 F16` or `"F01" "F02" "F03" "F04" "F05" "F06" "F07" "F08" "F09" "F10" "F11" "F12" "F13" "F14" "F15" "F16"`

Comment: Thanks so much. Was looking for the latter one with quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. 
After extracting the start and end of range from `s_q`, you can use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) to generate your list like so.

```
import re
s = '"F01" le code le "F16"'

s_q = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', s)
#['F01', 'F16']

#Extract the first and last index of range from list
first_code = int(s_q[0][1:])
#1
last_code = int(s_q[1][1:])
#16

#Create the result list
li = ['F{:02d}'.format(item) for item in range(first_code, last_code+1)]

#Get the final string with quotes
result = '"{}"'.format('" "'.join(li))

print(result)
```

The output will be

```
"F01" "F02" "F03" "F04" "F05" "F06" "F07" "F08" "F09" "F10" "F11" "F12" "F13" "F14" "F15" "F16"
```

Comment: OP wanted a string, so `print(*result)` will help